# ASP.NET website structure

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I am beginning an ASP.NET website and am pretty new to this. Could anyone help me on how to best structure my web pages.

It's one main page with a right and left pane. The left pane contains a menu. When the user clicks on any menu item the right pane gets populated with the relevant data.

Should I have one page with all the code and each menuitem clicked will never involve another page?
This will make it that when loading the main page all code and  javascript must load at that time. Correct?

Or should I have an iframe in the right pane that loads a separate aspx page for each menu item.
I feel like the 2nd approach is better for my needs because it sepaate the code for each menuitem however, I got stuck when I wanted to make a popup. Where should it go? On the main page or does each individual page get its own?
If I put it on the main page then the javascript needed for any popup will have to be on the main page. This sounds like it's messier than it should be.

Any ideas would bemuch appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use separate pages for each menu item. Use Master page for layout of website. You should develop popups in pages where it will need.

Comment: I thought about master pages but decided against  because I don't want to load a new page for every menuitem clicked. I use callbacks to populate the right pane.